# Controlling editing in NSTableView

Tags: macos, nstableview

I have subclassed NSTableView and NSTableColumn, and I want to control processus of edition of the cells of the table.

I have 2 states for my table class: edition and nonedition.
whatever the state of the table, when the user select a row, the row has to be overlighted.

if the table is in state edition, the controls corresponding to the selected row must be visible.

I use the function rowview to make this possible, but I have no success.
1 when I click on the text cell of a cell, the control appears always.
2 when the rowview function is called, I don't understand the value of the row parameter. Sometimes it is correct, sometimes it is incorrect.

is it someone who could hep me?

Comment: Why did you subclass `NSTableView` and `NSTableColumn` and which methods did you override? Which `NSTableViewDelegate` methods are implemented? Where are the controls, inside each row or outside the table view?

Comment: this is a very long story. In fact, I subclass all the apple control components, because I want them to interacts each other in my manner. I'm tired of writte and re-writte code, so I have written those subclassed components. And it works perfectly well, except that I put them recently in a pod.

And by making this pod, the reactions of the tableview is not the same. For instance, I overrided the function rowView(atRow row: Int, makeIfNecessary: Bool) and when I select the first row this function is called by the system with the value of row equal to 1, not 0.

Answer (score 0):

I want to make precision: to simplyfy, in my subclassed NSTableView, I write this code: 
    `override func rowView(atRow row: Int, makeIfNecessary: Bool) -> NSTableRowView? { 
        let aRow = super.rowView (atRow: row, makeIfNecessary: makeIfNecessary) 
        if aRow != nil { 
            Swift.print("rowview is called for row (row)") 
        } 
        return aRow 
    }`

When I click on row 0, I have the following result: "**rowview is called for row 1**"
Then when I click on row 1: "**rowview is called for row 1** rowview is called for row 0 rowview is called for row 2"